# How to read Auto Keyframing state in Python?

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

I want to create keyframes with Python, when a custom control changes. How do I check the state of the Auto Keyframing button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip turn on developer extras and tooltips in ***`Edit > Preferences > Interface > Display`***

Then mouse over the button and will see that it is boolean property to turn on off.  https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ToolSettings.html#bpy.types.ToolSettings.use_keyframe_insert_auto

```
scene.tool_settings.use_keyframe_insert_auto
```

Use in conjunction with the enum  https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ToolSettings.html#bpy.types.ToolSettings.auto_keying_mode

```
scene.tool_settings.auto_keying_mode
```